# How do the initialization is done in propertysheet?

Tags: mfc

I am having propertysheet where I had overriden OnInitDialog in CPropertySheet derived class
as follows,

```
BOOL CMySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
  CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
 //Once the call reached this point and after this my first page OnInitDialog is being called.
//Only first page onInitDialog is being called and it is not calling the remaining pages     //OnInitDialog.why?
//I am not sure how this calling or mapping is being done.

}
```

//CMySheet is derived from CPropertySheet

can anyone please explain me how all this mapping is being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**how to correctly add the pages:**
you can immagine a [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d3fkt014.aspx) as a dialog container, so its main job is to contain other dialogs [CPropertyPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/491c89bk.aspx).
So firstly i would say that you have to create your [CPropertyPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/491c89bk.aspx)s: so create the resources, classes etc...
Then you add the pages using [CPropertySheet::AddPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/y2ed8wah.aspx) method, but you don't have to do it in the [CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0bw65cxb.aspx) you can do it in the constructor or even outside the class but the important thing is that you do it before you call the [CPropertySheet::DoModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8xk61eyw.aspx) because that is the moment where the [CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0bw65cxb.aspx) will be called.

something like this:

```
CMySheet *pSheet = new CMySheet();
CMyPage *pPage = new CMyPage();
pSheet->AddPage(pPage);
INT_PTR iReturn = pSheet.DoModal();
```

**How stuff works:**
after you use the [CPropertySheet::DoModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8xk61eyw.aspx) method the [CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0bw65cxb.aspx) will be called, the [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d3fkt014.aspx) will then load the first page, because as i said it is a dialog container, and therefore it will show one dialog at a time, that's why you see only the first page loading, because the [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d3fkt014.aspx) is made to show only one [CPropertyPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/491c89bk.aspx) at a time! So each page will load separatedly, lets say when you click on a tree that stores the pages or when you click on the next button if you created a wizard, and not all at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After CpropertySheet::OnInitDialog call it is going first page OnInitDialog and again return back .My doubt is why it is going for only first page OnInitDialog() and why not it is going to other Pages OnInitDialog().That is my doubt.

Comment: oh ok! i got it now, i will modify my answer then!

Comment: you're welcome, we all get in these kind of problems some time ehehehehh